# Insert new row based on data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

(the data is not actually a log file but this simplifies the request)

I have log data in rows in a table named log that has specific start and end points. For example:

```
1001 | **start
1002 | log action
1003 | another action
1004 | log action
1005 | another action
1006 | **end
1007 | **start
1008 | log action
1009 | another action
1010 | log action
1011 | another action
```

I have another table named events which stores the start and end time of a log, the ID and some other meta data.

The data inside the log table is inserted in bulk. I would like, preferably within SQL to carry out the following actions:

1. Extract the rows between **start and **end
2. Insert a new row into events with the start and end time
3. Update the rows related to that event with the event ID

If the first entry it finds is an **end, it should skip this altogether and look for the next set. If the set it finds is missing an **end, it should skip this too until it finds the next set. Therefore, in the above example, rows 1001 through to 1006 would be used to create a new event entry and have that entries ID applied back to them.

The logic for this is relatively simple if I run a separate process that extracts the data from SQL (using BETWEEN) and then does its own calculations however this feels generally messy. I am looking for a solution to do the same thing in SQL.

Comment: You normally shouldn't put log files in a database. That being said, you could probably use a trigger to insert events into your other table.

Comment: They're not actually log files. GPS tracking, speed etc. I just figured logs was easier to explain how they were appearing, as above. I can see how writing a trigger would resolve the initial creation in the event table but I cannot fathom how that would let me go back later and assign the event ID to those rows in the log table?

Comment: You would not be able to update the log table from a trigger on the log table - I missed that part of your question. If you can use a stored procedure for creating new log entries, it can do everything you specified.